# Mongodb match if all elements in array are false

Tags: mongodb

I have a problem in MongoDB. I need to find all items where array only contains false key

My items looks like this

```json
{
 "field1" : "firstTest",
 "field2" : [
  {
   "name" : "test1",
   "use" : false
  },
  {
   "name" : "test2",
   "use" : true
  },
  {
   "name" : "test3",
   "use" : false
  }
 ],
 "updatedAt" : 2019-02-03T23:00:00.000+00:00
}
```

I need to match all items where field2 array only contains "use" key to false and "updatedAt" date is less than 3 years

I've start with something like :

```js
await client.db(db).collection(collection).aggregate([{ 
 $match:{
  $and:[
   {
    field2: { $elemMatch: { use: { $all: [false] } }}
   },
   {
    updatedAt: { $lt: moment().subtract(3,'years').toDate()} 
   }
  ]
 }
}])
```

But it looks like my field2 query does not work

Do you have any idea how to match on boolean properties in array ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using `$not` and `$elemMatch`

test it at [mongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hSNpuuf_81r)

```
await client.db(db).collection(collection).aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "$and": [
        {
          "field2": {
            $not: {
              $elemMatch: {
                use: {
                  $ne: false
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          updatedAt: { $lt: moment().subtract(3,'years').toDate()} 
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```